# DHCP/DNS hostname changes

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, dhcp, printing, hostname

I have a slightly oddball question, I have a Windows 2008 DC running DHCP and DNS, the problem I have is: 
1 - HP Multifunction Printer connected to network picks up DHCP IP Address

2 - The hostname picked up and added to DNS is eg NP18832 (or similar)

3 - The hostname is changed on the printer and rebooted, but neither DHCP or DNS update with the new hostname.

The DHCP server is setup to enable DNS dynamic updates and is set to always dynamically update A and PTR records.

Any idea's would be great

EDIT: 
Please see my comment below - I appreciate my question could have been misleading I know that best practice is to use a static IP.
The alternative is to use a DHCP range printing direct to hostname. The KB - KB967363 resolves my issue - thank you to those who tried to help.

Comment: Just to update my post - for everyones information there is a Hot fix to correct the behaviour which I have described above. I appreciate the comments regarding static dhcp leases but the issue does 100% still apply to them. The hotfix is KB967363 - thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Configure the HP with a static ip address.
2. Yes, that looks like an HP host name.
3. Delete the ip address lease in DHCP after you've configured the HP with a static ip address. Delete the A and PTR record in your DNS zone and let the HP re-register with DNS.

Comment: HI Joe, thanks for coming back to me. yup your right it is a HP hostname, we were trying to avoid having to bin the lease and records then let it pick them up again! - just really wondering if it is possible since the dhcp scope options make it sound so!

Comment: Accepted joes answer as it was first - my solution is actually in my comment many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Printers really should be either on a static IP, or ideally, have a DHCP reservation in your DHCP server so it always picks up the same IP address.  Some HP printers are flaky with registering DNS, so if you make a DHCP reservation, and manually create the A record, you'll have no ongoing issues.